# Classifying singularities of $f(z) = (\frac{z+3}{2z-1})^2$

Tags: complex-analysis

Classify the singularities of $f(z) = (\frac{z+3}{2z-1})^2$.

In the following solution [Solution](https://gyazo.com/f821bec3f1616e6f4a784f8e9a03681c) to the question on finding and classifying singularities, I'm having trouble understanding the "g(z) doesn't annihilate" part. What significance does that have? I know that the denominator has a zero of order two as explained. Also, a theorem that 1/h subsequently has a pole of order two at 1/2. But how is it deduced that g/h has a pole of order two at 1/2?

Comment: If you develop the Taylor series for $g$ around $z=1/2$ it is holomorphic with non-zero constant coefficient (equal to $g(1/2)$).  Then you divide by $4(z-1/2)^2$ and get a Laurent series with pole of order 2.

Answer (score 1):

Saying a function "annihilates" or "vanishes"
at a certain point is just an overly dramatic way of saying its value is 0 there. The denominator of a fraction, of course, can't be 0.

Do you understand the basic definitions here?  A function, f(z), has a "singularity" at $z= z_0$ if f is not continuous there.  There are three types of singularity.

1. A "removable singularity".  We can "remove" the singularity by simply redefining $f(z_0)$. For example, f(z)= z for any z except 1 and f(1)= 2.
2. A "pole of order n".  That is the case when $\lim_{z\to z_0} f(z)(z- z_0)^n$ exists but $\lim_{z\to z_0} f(z)(z- z_0)^m$ does not for any m< n.
3. An "essential singularity".  Basically any singularity that does not fit the first two.

This function, $f(z)= \left(\frac{z+ 3}{2z- 1}\right)^2= \frac{(z+ 3)^2}{(2z- 1)^2}$ is clearly continuous at all z except z= 1/2 where the denominator is 0 while the numerator is not.

$f(z)(z- 1/2)= (1/2)\frac{(z+ 3)^2}{(2z- ]12)^2}(2z- 1)= (1/2)\frac{(z+ 3)^2}{2z- 1}$ also is not continuous at z= 1/2 bcause the denominator is still 0 there.

But $f(z)(z- 1/2)^2= (1/4)\frac{(z+ 3)^2}{(2z- 1)^2}(2z- 1)^2= (1/4)(z+ 3)^2$  **is** continuous at z= 1/2.

Therefore, $f(z)= \left(\frac{z+ 3}{2z- 1}\right)^2$ has a "pole of order 2" at z= 1/2.

Answer (score 0):

You have\begin{align}f(z)&=\frac{(z+3)^2}{4(z-1/2)^2}\\&=\frac{((z-1/2)+7/2)^2}{4(z-1/2)^2}\\&=\frac{49/4+7(z-1/2)+(z-1/2)^2}{4(z-1/2)^2}\\&=\frac{49}{16}\left(z-\frac12\right)^{-2}+\frac74\left(z-\frac12\right)^{-1}+\frac14,\end{align}and therefore $f$ has a pole of order $2$ at $\frac12$.

Note that if the numerator of $f$ was *any* analytic function $g$ such that $g\left(\frac12\right)\ne0$, a similar approach would show that $f$ has a pole of order $2$ at $\frac12$.

Comment: Shouldn't you add $7/2$ instead of $1/2$ in the numerator in the second step?

Comment: @basilisk I've edited my answer. Thank you.